# Styling lists inline versus inline-block

Tags: css

I am trying to better understand CSS display inline versus block.

I have the following code below (live demo at http://jsfiddle.net/BfZEv/1/)

I have a list of blocks, and style them display:inline.  Why are they not inline?

I then tried inline-block, and it worked.  Reading the description of inline block, I would not have expected it to work.  Am I using it correctly

I then tried the final list, and almost got the appearance that I was looking for.  I want one row, but after each "Hello", I wanted to show the background image.  Can you help?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .main-ul-bad > li {
                list-style-type: none;
                display:inline
            }
            .main-ul > li {
                list-style-type: none;
                display:inline-block
            }
            div.div1 {
                display:inline-block
            }
            .main-ul > li div ul {
                display: none;
            }
            span.background {
                background-image: url("dropdown_arrow_blue.gif");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="main-ul-bad">
            <li><div>Hello</div></li>
            <li><div>Hello</div></li>
            <li><div>Hello</div></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="main-ul">
            <li><div>Hello</div></li>
            <li><div>Hello</div></li>
            <li><div>Hello</div></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="main-ul">
            <li>
                <span>Label</span>
                <div class="div1">
                    <div class="div2"><span class="text">Hello</span><span class="background"></span></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Hello</li>
                        <li>Hello</li>
                        <li>Hello</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Label</span>
                <div class="div1">
                    <div class="div2"><span class="text">Hello</span><span class="background"></span></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Hello</li>
                        <li>Hello</li>
                        <li>Hello</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Label</span>
                <div class="div1">
                    <div class="div2"><span class="text">Hello</span><span class="background"></span></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Hello</li>
                        <li>Hello</li>
                        <li>Hello</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first list `main-ul-bad` doesn't display inline because you have a `div` within each list item, which is a block by default. If you remove the divs or make them `inline`, they will show on one line.

http://jsfiddle.net/BfZEv/6/

Though I believe the more common, and possibly proper, way to do horizontal lists is to float them:

```
<ul class="main-ul-bad">
    <li><div>Hello</div></li>
    <li><div>Hello</div></li>
    <li><div>Hello</div></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.main-ul-bad {
    width: 500px;
}

.main-ul-bad > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Give the list a width that accommodates the number of items you want in one line and float the items.

Comment: I see that display isn't inherited, so that kind of makes sense.  But it seems that I would still have a horizontal list of <li>s, but then vertical divs within each.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by vertical divs?

Comment: I would expect the <li> elements to be inline and go horizontally across the screen, but within each, the <div> elements (if there were more than one) would be on top of each other since they are block.

Comment: Oh yes, that's because the `>` in the `... li > div` selector selects only direct children. If there are nested divs, they won't be selected. If you remove the `>`, it will effect all child divs. I updated my jsfiddle link to show ya.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your `<div>`-s `inline-block` as well, not just the `<li>`-s - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BfZEv/3/)

And then you can add the images after each one:

```css
.main-ul-bad > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

.main-ul-bad > li div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.main-ul-bad > li div:after {
    content: url(http://lorempixel.com/20/20);
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zoltan.  Why the use of position?

Comment: Just to be able to put the image wherever you want it to be.. An example without the positioning - http://jsfiddle.net/BfZEv/5/